# C# Garbage Collection: Objects in heap space

Tags: arrays, object, garbage-collection

I just learned about 85000 and the LOH after some play in WinDBG.

While viewing an instance of an object, in memory, I noted that the object was small (I might have a skewed view of languages above asm) and simply had primitives and references to the objects it "contained".

So what Id like to know is: are instances of objects "self-contained" from a  garbage collection point of view? ie; will the garbage collector treat each object as seperate objects? :)

My Q sounds stupid when I ask it like that; What constitutes the size of an object? Primitive and references only? Or the object and all its reference objects and their primitives, etc?

My worry is fragmentation, but my guess is that the LOH will only be provoked by arrays right?

That opens another Q; how can I avoid the LOH with arrays; say 3D meshes, cache, etc? Or are these valid LOH candidates and they should be treated with care... what care?